# Shouldn't I get tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have written this question: [Is there a quick key command that will switch frames in Flash?](https://superuser.com/questions/151900/is-there-a-quick-key-command-that-will-switch-frames-in-flash) and have not gotten answers for a month and only 29 views. I think that qualifies for a Tumbleweed badge, does it not?

Comment: +1 because I feel guilty for giving it an extra view. :-D

Comment: When did that question get a vote? That might affect it.

Comment: @random: I don't remember it has been soooo long, but I think I got the up-vote shortly after I posted the question.

Comment: That upvote probably killed your Tumbleweedleness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the timeline for your question - https://superuser.com/posts/151900/timeline -
you received a +1 vote on the day that you posted the question.

As random indicated in the comments, given this was in the first week it will have blocked you from getting the badge for this question.

Comment: There's a timeline view ? O_0 a year in SU and never knew of this!

Comment: I think it's a fairly well hidden feature (much like using superuser.com/reputation for example), found it mentioned on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) Meta.SO question.

Comment: @DMA - it's hidden because it still needs some work to be shown to the public, as of today.

Comment: @Gnoupi A good point. Still, I wonder, is there a place those of us interested in the useful but not very pretty/not quite working/might be coming soon type features can easily find word of them (other than obviously trawling over all of meta.SO)?

Comment: @DMA - the community tries to maintain a list of new features [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Gnoupi Thanks, it's on my meta fav's list